# ItemSimilarityJob user file (or item file)

Tags: hadoop, mahout, recommendation-engine

I'm using Mahout's `ItemSimilarityJob` to calculate the similarity between items. Is there any way of applying something similar to `usersfile` parameter of `RecommenderJob` to `ItemSimilarityJob`? What I want is not to have a complete similarity matrix each time I run it but only for some items. Think that I may have 1000 new items each day. So I want to avoid calculating similarity between the items I have seen previously (since I already calculated this).

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but you could add this fairly easily and contribute it back to the project.